# Finding the line number of a matched pattern without using enumerate

Tags: python, text-processing, enumerate

I want to find the line number of a pattern in a file without using enumerate.
Are there any Python libraries which directly give line numbers of a pattern?

Comment: You can always make your homebrew and utterly pointless `enumerate` with `zip(itertools.count(), file)`.

Comment: On a more serious note, this looks like a XY problem. WHY do you need this, what are you actually trying to do and what qualifies as getting the line number "directly"?

Comment: actually I have many separate codes in which different patterns are searched from many files, now I also want the line number of that patterns without changing much in each code

Comment: Leveraging `enumerate` is probably the least amount of change you can get away with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
>>> content = open('your_file').read()
>>> content[:content.find(your_pattern)].count('\n') + 1
line number of your_pattern in your_file
```

assuming your_pattern is contained.
If it would be clear why you need to know this and what the actual problem is, I could help you more.